# Wrong shape of tensor

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I'm trying to run the following code for Convolutional Autoencoder found on the Keras blog https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html. However, I'm getting an error message:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(1, 28, 28))

x = Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same')(x)
x = Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same')(x)
x = Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is (8, 4, 4) i.e. 128-dimensional

x = Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Convolution2D(1, 3, 3, activation='sigmoid', border_mode='same')(x)
print(decoded.get_shape())

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta',
                    loss='binary_crossentropy'
                   )

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                nb_epoch=50,
                batch_size=128,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test)
               )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-5ca753acfdbb> in <module>()
     28                 batch_size=128,
     29                 shuffle=True,
---> 30                 validation_data=(x_test, x_test)
     31                )

C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, nb_epoch, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch)
   1036                                                            class_weight=class_weight,
   1037                                                            check_batch_dim=False,
-> 1038                                                            batch_size=batch_size)
   1039         # prepare validation data
   1040         if validation_data:

C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_batch_dim, batch_size)
    965                                    output_shapes,
    966                                    check_batch_dim=False,
--> 967                                    exception_prefix='model target')
    968         sample_weights = standardize_sample_weights(sample_weight,
    969                                                     self.output_names)

C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_dim, exception_prefix)
    109                                         ' to have shape ' + str(shapes[i]) +
    110                                         ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 111                                         str(array.shape))
    112     return arrays
    113 

Exception: Error when checking model target: expected convolution2d_92 to have shape (None, 4, 28, 1) but got array with shape (60000, 1, 28, 28)
```

The dimension of decoded, which I printed out, is `(?, 4, 28, 1)`, which appears to be what the model is expecting, given the error message. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was happening? I'm having the same error running their example.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was accidentally using the Theano backend, when I should have been using the Tensorflow backend. In the theano backend, the first coordinate denotes the shape of the individual tensor, but it's the other way around in tensorflow. For example, for `input_img`, in Theano it is of shape `(1, 28, 28)`, but it is `(28, 28, 1)` in Tensorflow.